# How to chose a variable depending on probability?

Tags: java, random, probability

I have 35 variables (a1, a2... a34, a35) and each one of them has a number that represents its probability of being picked.

```
int a1 = 100/i;
int a2 = a1 * 2;
int a3 = a2 * 3;
int a4 = a3 * 4;
```

With math.Random() I would get a random number between 1 and 100 and the variable that contains that number would be chosen. This last part is the one I can't do.

a1 would have the numbers 0-2.5

a2 would have the numbers 2.6-5

a3 would have the numbers 5.1-7.5

Comment: You can save yourself a lot of effort by using an array instead of 35 individual variables.

Comment: And a little effort by using `java.util.Random` instead of `Math.random()`.

Comment: can you be more specific I dont get what you want to achieve

Comment: Try to use a for loop

Comment: From your code it seems that a2 = 2*a1, a3 = 3*a1 etc. so you'd basically just need a random number between 1 and 35 and multiply that with the value for a1.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by something like this:

```
int [] myValues = new int[35];
myValues[0] = 100/i; // a1
int prevValue = myValues[0];
for (int idx = 1; idx < 35; idx++) {
    myValues[idx] = prevValue * (idx + 1);
    prevValue  = myValues[idx];
}

Random rand = new Random(); 
int randomIndex = rand.nextInt(35);  // get random Number between 0 and 34 (incl.)
System.out.println("My Value is " + myValues[randomIndex ]);
```